# How to use "repne scasb" in GAS assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

So I have written a program based on NASM that receives user input (two numbers to be exact), and then it realizes the addition and difference between the two numbers, and then it prints it back. The program works fine in NASM but I am having trouble with GAS. The subroutine that counts the length of a string using the `repne scasb` instruction is giving me a headache because of a segmentation fault.

I have checked the code for segmentation faults, and I have located the fault in the `repne scasb` line.

What I am basically doing is translating a NASM code I made into its respective GAS code. However, as I said before, it's giving me a segmentation fault. After I get the first number from the user, to be more specific.

```
.section .data
    msg:                .ascii "Insert a number: "
    msgLen              = .-msg

    msg2:               .ascii "Insert another number: "
    msg2Len             = .-msg2

    errorMsg:           .ascii "Error: invalid character!\n"
    errorMsgLen         = .-errorMsg

    displaySuma:        .ascii "The result of the addition is: "
    displaySumaLen      = .-displaySuma

    displayResta:       .ascii "The result of the difference is: "
    displayRestaLen     = .-displayResta

    enterChar:          .ascii "\n"

    terminator:         .byte 0

.section .bss
    .lcomm num1, 8

    .lcomm num2, 8

    .lcomm buffer, 10
    .lcomm buffer2, 10

.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    call _clear                 #clear registers. Probably an useless routine
    call _msg1                  #Display msg1
    call _num1                  #Read num1

    movl num1, %edi

    call _lenString             #ECX now has num1 length

    lea (num1), %esi
    call _stringToInt           #EAX now has num1 in integer

    movl %eax, %r15d            #R15D now has the integer

    call _msg2                  #Display msg2
    call _num2                  #Read num2

    xor %edi, %edi              #Clear EDI
    movl num2, %edi         #Moving num2 to EDI register to call _lenstring
    xor %ecx, %ecx              #Clear ECX

    call _lenString             #ECX has num2 length

    xor %esi, %esi              #clear ESI
    lea (num2), %esi
    call _stringToInt           #EAX now has integer value of num2

    mov %eax,%r14d              ###R14D has num2 now

    #Addition
    #r8d = num1 + num2
    mov %r15d, %r8d
    add %r14d, %r8d             #R8D has num1 + num2

    #Difference
    #If num1 > num2    =======> r9d = num1 - num2
    #If num1 < num2    =======> r9d = num2 - num1
    cmp %r14d, %r15d
    jg .greater

    mov %r14d, %r9d
    sub %r15d, %r9d             #R9D has num1 - num2
    jmp .next

.greater:
    mov %r15d, %r9d
    sub %r14d, %r9d             #R9D has num2 - num1
    jmp .next

.next:
    mov %r8d, %eax              #Sum is now at EAX to convert it to ascii characters

    lea (buffer), %esi
    call _intToString
    #EAX ascii of the sum

    mov %eax, %r10d             #Using R10D to store the new string

    mov %r9d, %eax              #Difference result is now at EAX

    lea (buffer2), %esi
    call _intToString
    #EAX has the pointer to the difference result.

    mov %eax, %r11d             #Storing string in R10D

    xor %edi, %edi
    xor %r15d, %r15d
    xor %r14d, %r14d

    mov %r10d, %edi
    call _lenString             #ECX length of sum string
    mov %ecx, %r15d             #R15D now has that value

    call _suma                              #This prints the sum result

    xor %edi, %edi              #Clear EDI
    mov %r11d, %edi     
    call _lenString             #ECX has length of dif. string
    mov %ecx, %r14d             #R14D has that value

    call _resta                             #Print dif. result

    movl $1, %eax               #End of the program
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

_stringToInt:
    xor %ebx, %ebx

.next_digit:
    movzxb (%esi), %eax

    cmp $0x30, %eax                         #These 4 lines check for invalid characters
    jb _errorMsg
    cmp $0x39, %eax
    ja _errorMsg

    inc %esi
    sub $0x30, %eax             ###Sub 48 (converts to integer)
    imul $10, %ebx              
    add %eax, %ebx              #ebx = ebx*10 + eax
    loop .next_digit            #loop [ECX] times
    mov %ebx, %eax
    ret

_intToString:
    add $10, %esi
    mov (terminator),%esi

    mov $10, %ebx

.next_digit1:
    xor %edx, %edx
    div %ebx
    add $0x30, %edx             ##
    dec %esi
    mov %dl, (%esi)
    test %eax, %eax
    jnz .next_digit1
    mov %esi, %eax
    ret


#######################################################################################################


_msg1:
    movl $4, %eax                       #msg1 routine
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $msg, %ecx
    movl $msgLen, %edx
    int $0x80
    ret

_num1:
    movl $3, %eax                       #Reads first number
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $num1, %ecx
    movl $8, %edx
    int $0x80
    ret

_msg2:
    movl $4, %eax                       #msg2 display
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $msg2, %ecx
    movl $msg2Len, %edx
    int $0x80
    ret

_num2:
    movl $3, %eax                       #Reads the next number
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $num2, %ecx
    movl $8, %edx
    int $0x80
    ret

_salir:
    movl $1, %eax                       #Exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

_errorMsg:
    movl $4, %eax                       #Error msg
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $errorMsg, %ecx
    movl $errorMsgLen, %edx
    int $0x80

    jmp _salir

_lenString:
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    not %ecx
    xor %al, %al
    mov $0xA, %al
    cld
    repne scasb                     #Segmentation fault is caused by this line
    not %ecx
    dec %ecx
    ret

_suma:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $displaySuma, %ecx
    movl $displayRestaLen, %edx
    int $0x80

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    mov %r10d, %ecx
    mov %r15d, %edx
    int $0x80

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $enterChar, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80
    ret

_resta:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $displayResta, %ecx
    movl $displayRestaLen, %edx
    int $0x80

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    mov %r11d, %ecx
    mov %r14d, %edx
    int $0x80

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $enterChar, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80
    ret

_clear:
    xor %eax, %eax
    xor %ebx, %ebx
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    xor %edx, %edx
    xor %esi, %esi
    xor %edi, %edi
    xor %r8d, %r8d
    xor %r9d, %r9d
    xor %r10d, %r10d
    xor %r11d, %r11d
    xor %r14d, %r14d
    xor %r15d, %r15d
    ret
```

I am using this makefile to create the .o and .exe files (Given by my professor):

```
#*************************************************
# Executable name : hola
# Version : 2.0
# Created date : February 12, 2019
# Authors : 
#   Eduardo A. Canessa M
# Description : simple makefile for GAS
# Important Notice: To be used for GAS only
#*************************************************
#change the name "ejemplo" for the name of your source file
name=addSubInteger
#program to use as the assembler (you could use NASM or YASM for this makefile)
ASM=as
#flags for the assember
#ASM_F= #*** place here flags if needed ***

#program to use as linker
LINKER=ld

#link executable
$(name): $(name).o
    $(LINKER) -o $(name) $(name).o

#assemble source code
$(name).o: $(name).s
    $(ASM) $(ASM_F) -o $(name).o $(name).s
```

There is a segmentation fault error after the program reads the first user input.

This is [the NASM code of my program](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tWoNvHj7r64eBJUSDCULJF-PbsZ3alNV?usp=sharing) (Hope you don't mind the spanish comments in it, but it's essentially the same program as the one written on GAS).

I know I have made some next level spaghetti code, but this is the solution I came to.

Comment: Note that `mov num1, %edi` moves the value at address `num1` into `%edi`.  That's probably not what you want.  Try `mov $num1, %edi` or `lea num1(%rip), %edi` instead.

Comment: @fuz Obviously the user uses 32-bit assembly. This means that `lea num1(%rip), %edi` won't work; `lea num1, %edi` should.

Comment: @MartinRosenau No, that's 64 bit assembly.  Though weirdly, it exclusively uses 32 bit registers and the 32 bit `int $0x80` interface.  I smell problems down the road when OP tries to store anything on the stack.

Comment: @fuz Oh. I didn't see the use of registers like `%r9d`.

Comment: @fuz okay I tried using the ```mov $num1,  %edi``` but now there is a segmentation fault in the intToString routine. It has to do with ```mov %dl, (%esi)```

Comment: @ProgrammerFailure In `intToString`, you overwrite the address in `esi` with the content of `terminator`.  This doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> movl num1, %edi
> call _lenString             #ECX now has num1 length
> lea (num1), %esi
> call _stringToInt           #EAX now has num1 in integer
> ```

The first instruction does not load the address in `%edi`. You can use `lea` like you did for the call to *_stringToInt* that follows next. Or if you care about a shorter encoding then write `mov $num1, %edi`.

```
lea  (num1), %edi
call _lenString             #ECX now has num1 length
```

The same problem exists for the second number:

> ```
> movl num2, %edi      SAME PROBLEM
> xor %ecx, %ecx
> call _lenString
> ```

---

The *_intToString* subroutine has 2 problems!

1. You destroy the address in `%esi` by writing a random value in it.
2. You (try to) write in memory beyond the buffer that was reserved via `.lcomm buffer, 10`. This will destroy the first byte in *buffer2*.

Since converting a 32-bit integer can produce (at most) 10 characters, you will need to enlarge your buffer to 11 bytes so you can safely store the byte-sized terminator.

```
.lcomm buffer, 11
.lcomm buffer2, 11
```

Then use this code:

```
_intToString:
  mov  $10, %ebx
  add  %ebx, %esi      #Instead of 'ADD $10, %ESI' now that EBX==10
  mov  (terminator), %dl
  mov  %dl, (%esi)
.next_digit1:
  xor  %edx, %edx
  div  %ebx
  add  $0x30, %edx             ##
  dec  %esi
  mov  %dl, (%esi)
  test %eax, %eax
  jnz  .next_digit1
  mov  %esi, %eax
  ret
```

The original NASM source uses

```
STRING_TERMINATOR   equ 10
```

An `equ` does not consume memory at run-time. Your `terminator: .byte 0` does use run-time memory! A good translation for the `equ` would be

```
.set terminator,0
```

Now you can write

```
_intToString:
  mov  $10, %ebx
  add  %ebx, %esi      #Instead of 'ADD $10, %ESI' now that EBX==10
  movb $terminator, (%esi)
```